# Can a single buck converter be used for converting both 12V and 24V input to a constant 12V output DC to be fed into a 12V DC motor?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, 12v, 24v

My target is to design a low-cost PCB to run a 12V DC motor. I do need to have 2 input sources, a 12VDC and a 24VDC. What is the best way to achieve this using a single board? Can I use a single buck converter to convert both 12V and 24V into a 12V regulated output? This will be the input to 12V DC motor. Is there a better way to do it cost effectively? I want to keep the price below 5$ per board.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What is the power rating of the motor?  How much current will the load draw under worst-case (highest current) conditions?  What is the power source?

Comment: Do you need both input voltage sources to work at the same time (redundant)? Or will the inputs be one or the other and not both?

Comment: (Is this "automotive"?) What is the voltage range with the 12 V nominal power sources, and what is the acceptable deviation, ripple&noise with the output? Is the motor guaranteed to be a commutator type motor?

Comment: (The most simple topologies to support an output voltage either side of the input voltage should be Ćuk where opposite polarity is acceptable, else SEPIC. A commutator type motor may not need a clean DC supply.)

Comment: How much voltage can you afford to loose with 12 V input? Most buck converters will have less than 100 % duty cycle. PMOS ones capable of 100 % pass though does also exists.

Comment: i want to provide an option to have two input sources 12V and 24V in a single PCB although there will be only 1 input fed at a time. @MOSFET

Comment: The motor is a 12V brushed DC motor, with 390mA Max load current. @Fabio

Comment: I would like the 12V to be fed straight through and the 24V to be converted to 12V, to run a 12 V motor. @Winny

Comment: That part I understand, but you did not answer my question. How much voltage can you afford to loose with 12 V input?

Answer (score 0):

> *I do need to have 2 input sources, a 12VDC and a 24VDC.*

Common sense dictates that if you have a 12 volt input voltage then, that will naturally become the 12 volt feed to the motor. If you only have a 24 volt input supply then use a buck converter to drop it to 12 volts for the motor feed.

> *Is there a better way to do it cost effectively?*

I don't think so.

> *I want to keep the price below 5$ per board.*

That may not be possible if you need a powerful buck converter and, you shop at expensive places and, your design is difficult to test and, your circuit board is difficult to make. Cost doesn't just include component parts but also labour.

Comment: my original thought was to have branched input connections where: one node brings in a 12V input feed through direct and another with a 24V input source with a Linear regulator to convert 24V to 12V. Either one of the branch circuits will be the input for the motor at a time. The application is to run a 2W motor.

Comment: Your original thought (not what you wrote in your question) would dissipate 2 watts in dropping 24 volts to 12 volts thus, you would likely have to bear the cost of a heatsink.

Answer (score 0):

The following circuit will allow either 12V input, 15V-24V input, or both at the same time time. The exact range will depend on the buck convertor. If you know the the "24V input" is a constant 24 volts, you can replace the buck convertor with a 50% duty cycle oscillator. That should get the design a bit cheaper (no inductors and SMPS controllers necessary).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbo7nd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: 1N4148 is obviously a poor choice of diode here, but I take it that you just grabbed a random diode symbol. Also this converts 12V to 11.3V, which is one of the problems.

Comment: @Lundin. Well if the motor really is that intolerant to the input voltage, It is almost definitely going to need a complex convertor that can both boost and buck the input voltage. Either that, or the two (representative) diodes can be replaced with a "user selectable" SPDT switch to eliminate the diode drops.

Comment: @MOSFET, Thank you for validating my thought, anything we can do near the output end to regulate it to a 12V constant? The motor will be controlled via thyristor or MOSFET to run it at 3 different speeds.

Comment: @Adithi I suggest updating specific application details in your original post - it is not clear what you are exactly trying to do. What is the motor controlling? Thyristor control seems weird for a 3-speed DC motor control. I would love for you to elaborate.

Comment: 1N4148 may also be unsuitable because it can only handle 2A and a motor might need more than that. A schottky which can candle some more current and >30V reverse is the correct choice. Also TVS on both sides of the regulator.